# How do I control the SmartLocks blue banner?

Tags: android, credentials, google-smartlockpasswords

When the user starts the app, I'm able to retrieve a previously stored credential. When this happens, the blue SmartLock banner shows up. On the app I work on, this is covering a FAB making it unusable until the blue banner goes away. Is there a way to control the length of time the banner is shown? Additionally, is there a way to let the FAB move up like it would with a snackbar showing?

Lastly, if the user exits the app as the banner is showing, it will continue to show on the phone home screen, blocking any use of the bottom app bar. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Unfortunately, a known issue at the moment. Let me ask an Android UI designer for recommendations. We want to ensure the blue bar is shown on top of the app for sufficient time and user is informed that their credential was retrieved. Most apps only sign the user in one time with the API per device, so impact is smaller and we just haven't had a chance to polish the position and fix behavior when switching out of the app (which is relatively uncommon after immediately signing in for a normal user)

Comment: But as mentioned on another question, sounds like B&H may sign user back in regularly via the API (I sent David Weinberger an email asking for some background on this ... why does user's session expire, what is the value of signing in again on the same device?) Is http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html useful instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The auto sign-in banner is shown by Play Services and drawn over the app. The intent is to notify the user that their saved credentials have been retrieved and avoid app inadvertently not displaying or displaying the notification at an incongruous time or place.

Right now, there is not much flexibility about it, the banner won't be in the app view hierarchy and might cover other elements, such as floating action buttons, for a few seconds. In practice, we haven't found this to be much of an issue ... many apps have put the auto sign-in at start and it shows over a splash screen and only once per device install since most apps don't need to sign users out.

But fair concerns that if credentials might be retrieved frequently or user may interact or switch apps immediately after signing in. Do comment with any feedback/requests, examples of problematic scenarios, or suggestions of alternative UX or implementation we'll see if we can accommodate them.

Comment: I have a scenario where the SmartLock credentials are read successfully but the user has changed the password after originally saving the credentials so the automatic login fails. I'd like to show a snackbar with a manual Sign In action (or the user can keep using the app as an unsigned in user). Because the blue banner is shown and can't be dismissed, the snackbar is hidden behind it. Also it seems to be shown for Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG duration so I have to use INDEFINITE to get it to be visible after the banner has gone. Obviously I'm going to implement change password to smartlock too...

Comment: I am having some different use case. In my case the smart lock blue banner visible on the login screen and user get out of the activity by pressing the back press button. Then the banner still continue to visible to the user on the home screen of the device. this seems very bad to the user. Either we should have control to hide or get some call back of it.